# integer value changes in excel and includes E+11 like values

Tags: php, excel, header

How can I keep original format of an integer values after converting it into XLS file? Currently it changes and I see **E+** sign and some numbers at the end of the original value. Also zero(0) at the beginning disappears.

Thanks

```
$OUTPUT.= "<td>".$row["telephone"]."</td>";    //Original value 0852055504077

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=file.xls');
echo $OUTPUT;
```

**RESULT is 8.52056E+11**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to add an apostrophe (`'`) before the phone number:

```
$OUTPUT.= "<td>'".$row["telephone"]."</td>";
```

In that way you let Excel know not to interpret the value in that cell.

Comment: This time people will complain why ' sign is being added!

Comment: If the end-user is going to complain; you won't see the ' in Excel. If you mean other programmers will complain just put the reason in a comment.

Comment: I see ' in excel that's why I mentioned.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: starting from 2003 and others so the solution should be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it with some format like

```
countrycode XXXX XXXX
```

e.g->  091 98980 12345

Here :

```
 $telephone =  $row["telephone"];    // Suppose 0919898098980
 $OUTPUT.= "<td>".$telephone.substring."</td>";
 $len = strlen($telephone);
 echo $t = substr($telephone, 0,3)." ".substr($telephone, 3,5)." ".substr($telephone, 8); // Output : 091 98980 98980
 // Or you do can 
 echo $t = substr($telephone, 0,  ($len/2)+($len%2))." ".substr($telephone, ($len/2)+($len%2)); // output : 0919898 098980
```

Comment: what if the OP wants the number as is and not with spaces?